# Messages from the last 10 minutes can still be read after using Firebase Rules

Tags: json, firebase, time, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following rules in my Firebase Realtime Database:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages":{
      "$key":{
        // only messages from the last 10 minutes can be read
        ".read": "data.child('time').val() > (now - 600000)",
      }
    },
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

And the following data structure:

[image]

Unfortunately, messages that existed longer than 10 minutes can still be read. What's wrong with my code?

Summary: to read the children of a key, the user must be authenticated and 'time' has to be less than 10 minutes old (600000 milliseconds).

I'm afraid I'm running out of time to complete my work! I'm willing to award my bounty to whoever solves my problem.

Comment: How are you setting the time entry?

Comment: @Lewis I don't think that matters because whatever value I assign to 'time', nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it doesnt work is because you used the read after a read, so it replace the above read

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages":{
      "$key":{
        ".read": "auth != null && data.child('time').val() > (now - 600000)",
      }
    },
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

this will work fine

Answer (score 0):

This is to do with the way that Firebase rules cascade, as mentioned [in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/#section-authorization):

> Note that .read and .write rules shallower in the database override deeper rules

[This blog post](https://howtofirebase.com/firebase-security-rules-88d94606ce4a) further emphasises the point in a section about Rule Cascading, noting:

> Firebase rules cascade in such a way that granting a read or write privilege to a parent node *always* grants that read/write access to all child nodes.

So in this case, your rules giving access where `auth != null` are at the root level of the database and thus give read and write access to anyone who is a signed in(or anonymous authed) user, even if your other `.read` rule deeper in would seem to forbid this. The rule at the root level has priority and so your other rule based on time doesn't matter!

What you would need to do is remove the `.read` rule that is at the root level, which will allow your read rule for messages to be effective; then if you have separate sections in your database, give them their own rules as appropriate.

So if you had separate sections for "messages" and "users" your rules could look like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages":{
      "$key":{
        ".read": "data.child('time').val() > (now - 600000) && auth != null",
      }
    },
    "users":{
      ".read": "auth != null",
    },
  ".write": "auth != null",
  }
}
```

Where the "messages" `.read` rule requires the user be authorised and that it is within the specified time limit. The `.read` rule for data under the "users" node just requires an authorised user, and the "`.write` rule is at the root level so applies to everything any authorised user can write.

Comment: Thanks for your good answer. But, can you show me how I could put `".read": "data.child('time').val() > (now - 600000)"` and `".read": "auth != null"` (the latter for the entire database) at the same time properly in my case?

Comment: Users can't read at all. Let's investigate. Does my data structure match your code?

Comment: Revised summary: to read the children of a key, the user must be authenticated and 'time' has to be less than 10 minutes old (600000 milliseconds).

Comment: hmm, I don't have an actual project to fully test the situation. This rule should work for individual messages. This assumes you know the id of a message and try to read it, rather than attaching a listener to the "messages" node. If instead you want to ask for all children of the messages node that match the criteria, perhaps you should investigate using Query.

Comment: So, the code in your answer won't work with the data structure shown in my the question?  (multiple keys)

Comment: But, even with 1 individual message and knowing the key (ID), the user can't read anything...

Comment: Let's help each other. I tried this but it doesn't help: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data

Comment: @Programmer: Lewis's rule is correct for reading an _individual_ message.  The listener must be set on the specific message location, e.g `mDatabase.getReference("messages").child("msg1")`.  Note that his answer does not specify any rules for the `messages` node.  So trying to query `messages` using something like `mDatabase.getReference("messages").orderByChild("time")` will fail because access at location `messages` is not granted.  It is not possible to  specify the age condition you want for an individual message and have it applied in a query over all messages.

Comment: @Bob So, what's the best server-side solution to what I want to achieve?

Comment: @BobSnyder Feel free to write a new answer.